# How to set a X-CSRF token in $resource

Tags: angularjs, header, angular-resource

I'd like to add an X-CSRF token to some $resources, but even though I've been looking to other topic and found taht I could add header this way

```
return $resource(url, {}, {
              connect: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'headerName': value}
              }
            });
```

However I don't have the X-CSRFToken added in the request headers when I set headerName to CSRF-TOKEN or crsftoken, (same goes for `X-CSRF-TOKEN`)

Do someone has an idea why it's not working ?

Edit1: I've seen that add a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` added an header `X-XSRF-TOKEN` to my requests but `CSRF-TOKEN` does not.

Comment: @Antonie, are you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
this.exampleFunction = function (csrf) {
    return $resource(url, null, {
        'update': {'method': 'POST', headers: {'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN': csrf}},
    });
};
```

The header name may be different depending on the back end.
For Django it may be 'X-CSRFToken' or 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'.